# When I read from a file I am getting control characters

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to read from a file, but I keep getting control characters at the end of my string. I use the `for` loop to check for them and it prints out that there is one for every word, but only if I add the `+ 1` to `temp.size()`. I don't want to read them from the file. I am really confused why this is happening.

```cpp
int main(){
    ifstream inFile;
    vector<string> vect;
    string temp = "";

    //Reading from a file line by line
    inFile.open("words.txt");
    if (inFile.is_open())
    {
        while (!inFile.eof())
        {
            getline(inFile, temp);
            vect.push_back(temp);
        }
    }
    inFile.close();

    //checking through each character of the string to see if it has a control character.
    for (int i = 0; i < vect.size(); i++)
    {
        temp = vect[i];
        for (int j = 0; j < temp.size() + 1; j++)
        {
            if (iscntrl(temp[j]))
            {
                cout << temp << " There is a space\n";
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[image: .txt file image]

Comment: why are you not printing the code nor the position in the line of the control char ?

Comment: If you are on Windows, it may be that the CRLF line endings are reading the CR as part of the line rather than as part of the CRLF end-of-line marker.  Opening such files in text mode will treat the CRLF pair of characters as the end-of-line marker.  Or you can strip it off manually.

Comment: `getline()` handles bare-LF and CRLF line breaks on Windows.

Answer (score 7):

The root cause of your issue is that your `for` loop is accessing the `temp` string's **null-terminator** (technically, in a way that is *undefined behavior* prior to C++11).  `iscntrl()` considers character `'\0'` (0x00) to be a *control character*.  You need to change this:

```cpp
for (int j = 0; j < temp.size() + 1; j++)
```

to this:

```cpp
for (size_t j = 0; j < temp.size(); j++)
```

The null-terminator is not part of a `std::string`'s size/payload, but it is present for compatibility so that `std::string` can be used with C-based APIs.

---

Also, unrelated to that problem, your `while` loop is broken. See [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition (i.e. `while (!stream.eof())`) considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/).  You need to replace this:

```cpp
while (!inFile.eof())
{
    getline(inFile, temp);
    vect.push_back(temp);
}
```

with this:

```cpp
while (getline(inFile, temp))
{
    vect.push_back(temp);
}
```

Comment: @bruno Thank you so much! Il look into the post you linked

Comment: @natedawg is not me but RemyLebeau

Comment: @RemyLebeau Sorry about the mix up, thanks man! really appreciate it.